# ScrollViewer selects NumberBox by click to blank space

Tags: c#, uwp, scrollviewer

I have simple UWP project with ScrollViewer and NumberBox.
When user clicks to blank space a ScrollViewer selects first NumberBox in xaml file.

```
...
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
...

<ScrollViewer>
   <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
   <muxc:NumberBox/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image]

But if add some item like Combobox above then ScrollViewer does't select NumberBox

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
   <ComboBox />
   <muxc:NumberBox/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image]

If i delete ScrollViewer the NumberBox will not select when user clicks to blunk space.

```
<TextBlock Text="Some text" />
<muxc:NumberBox/>
```

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable select first item when click to blank space

```
<ScrollViewer IsTabStop="True">
```

Answer (score 0):

In ScrollViewer, the focus will be passed to the first focusable control in it's content, so when the ScrollViewer only has the TextBlock and NumberBox, NumberBox will get focus automatically. When you added the ComboBox in front of the NumberBox, the ComboBox get focus by default. In addition, if you delete the ScrollViewer, since the Grid panel does not derive from Control, it is not "focusable". The NumberBox won't get focus when you click the empty place.

If you want to select the NumberBox when you click the empty place, you could try to use [Control.Focus()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.focus?view=winrt-19041) method to set the focus on the NumberBox. For example:

.xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer PointerPressed="ScrollViewer_PointerPressed"  Tapped="ScrollViewer_Tapped">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
        <ComboBox></ComboBox>
        <muxc:NumberBox x:Name="MyNumberBox"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

.cs:

```
private void ScrollViewer_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(IsClicked)
        MyNumberBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    IsClicked = false;
}

private bool IsClicked { get; set; }

private void ScrollViewer_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsClicked = true;
}
```